# Methods to find user location with Accuracy in iOS5

Tags: iphone, google-maps, ios5, cllocation

I need to find user location in iPhone. I am able to find user's current location using `CLLocation Manager`. But the location which I am getting is not accurate to my physical device location. I have used the following criteria to set the accuracy

```
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 10;
    [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    [locationManager release];
```

When I try printing "newLocation.verticalAccuracy" and "newLocation.horizontalAccuracy" inside `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation`: method, most of the time I am getting around 10.0000 horizontal accuracy and 12.00000 vertical accuracy.

So, Is there any other method to find user location with better accuracy or am I missing any setting? Please help.

FYI: I am using WiFi and test in open place for better result.

Answer (score 1):

look this link

[LocateMe](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007801) sample demo project

or use this

Put in your .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface yourController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@end
```

and .m file

In the init method

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

and use this functions ..

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSLog(@"OldLocation %f %f", oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    NSLog(@"NewLocation %f %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the information. I am using the same function but still the location is not accurate with the physical location. Can anyone tell me how accurate is CLLocation? And does it depends on location?